# Bash - uploading multiple files to FTP using real path?

Tags: bash, csv, file-upload, ftp

I have this script to upload files to FTP (I know FTP is not secure, though client insists of using FTP..). It works fine, but the problem with it is does not recognize path provided when doing upload, even though message says it uploaded successfully, but nothing is uploaded.

So the script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=host  
USER=user           
PASS=pass        
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"


ftp -inv $HOST << EOF

user $USER $PASS

get
cd /path/in/ftp/

prompt
mput $DIR/*.csv

# End FTP Connection
bye

EOF

rm $DIR/*.csv
```

Here what is outputted:

```
Connected to host.
220 You have connected to Client's FTP server.
?Invalid command
331 User name okay, need password.
230-Welcome user from ip. You are now logged in to the server.
230 User logged in, proceed.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
?Invalid command
250 Directory changed to "/path/in/ftp/"
?Invalid command
Interactive mode on.
mput /path/inv_numbers_2016-11-21_12_09.csv? 200 PORT command successful.
150 File status okay; about to open data connection.
226 Closing data connection. Transferred 140 bytes in 1 seconds. 0KB/second.
140 bytes sent in 0.00 secs (1395.1 kB/s)
?Invalid command
221 Session Ended. Downloaded 0KB, Uploaded 1KB. Goodbye user from ip.
```

Now if I change `mput $DIR/*.csv` to `mput *.csv`, then it works (I get same log output like with previous one, except it shows path as being directly in directory where script is). But this only works if I would run script directly from directory it is placed in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
```

by

```
cd "$DIR" && ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
```

or by

```
cd "$DIR" || exit 1
ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
```

Comment: It looks this should work. I tested similar idea using: `cd "${0%/*}"`, before connecting to FTP and it works.